# How to send large json data to the spring controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

How can i send large volume of json data to a spring controller. Say, i have large json data of about 100k or 1000k records which i need to send to my rest controller in spring or springboot then what is the best/most efficient approach to solve the problem.

I know that the data can be sent using request body but i think sending such a large volume of data in the request body of a REST api is not efficient. I may be wrong here, please correct me if i am.

And the data needs to be stored in the database as quickly as possible. So, i need a quick and reliable approach to the problem.

Comment: I think the real issue will not be related to place in body using rest , as it will depend on your network latency and throughput.

Comment: Yeah sure it depends upon the network latency and throughput but there must be some more efficient way of doing such things. Sending large volume of data(~200-300mb) in the request body doesn't seem good to me

Comment: Then, I think you’re looking for such mechanism like paginated rest , check this https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/

Comment: That post was about receiving paginated json response. I have used pagination for accepting response many times. But here the problem is with sending the payload to the controller. Anyways, thanks for your time

Comment: You are right, let me try to suggest, you can send alternative type of request like file multi part, performance wise it should be more efficient.

Comment: Multipart file is definitely much better but sometimes there are some restrictions for using json payload only, life if we are consuming some third party api. So, in that case we need to find some better solution

Comment: from where you will be sending the data. will it be from browser or some from some other server side application?

Comment: it could be some third party api which i need to consume

Comment: @VishalSharma what was your approach here for the large payload? I am in a similar situation, wanted to checkout out the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to your problem.
1. How to receive such a huge volume: If there is a huge volume of data being received, its generally a good idea to save(from the input stream of the response) it locally as a file and process that data asynchronously.(Make sure you set an appropriately high read timeout, else the data stream might be interrupted ) .
2. How do you process such a huge file: With big files, memory footprint needs to be minimal. For XML , SaxParsers are a golden standard . I found this library which is very similar to sax parsing, but for Json
http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_sax.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use reactive approach and streaming the data.
With Spring, use `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE` producer and Flux as return type.
On the client side, subscribe to the stream and process the data, or you can use Spring Batch to save the data to the Database.