# Spring rest endpoint handling large list gives entity too large error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

I am seeing entity too large error from our Rest endpoint when we send large list, around 2k to 4k or so items. Is there a way for me to increase the limit or is there a limit on how much data we can send to the service?

[update]
code syntax:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/save", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> saveCampaign(@RequestBody CampaignDTO dto) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(campaignService.saveCampaign(dto));
}
```

Comment: You should send such a large list via the POST method.

Comment: We are using POST as our endpoint.

Comment: You should provide more details on how the list is transmitted.

Comment: Added code syntax.

Comment: Max allow payload size probably depends of the framework or system that you are using. It is node?

Comment: can you also add the exact error in the question? Are you deploying on Tomcat?

Comment: you can see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011717/how-to-send-large-json-data-to-the-spring-controller maybe it will help. I would search for the approach of the second answer